# сОбак, собАкин, собачИна

Tags: орфоэпия, однокоренные-слова, жаргон

Довольно часто в прессе, по телевидению, на улице, в транспорте можно встретиться с выражениями, которые описывают особое отношение к собакам:

"Какой прелестный сОбак!"

"Надеюсь, Ваш собАкин меня не тронет."

"Чего брешешь, собачИна вредная?"

Насколько применимо и опраданно *такое* произношение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не "произношение", это своего рода словотворчество, словообразование. Допустимость колеблется от разговорного до авторского эрратива.

Конечно, в строгой речи ни одно такое новообразование не применимо, это что-то фамильярно-ласковое, собаке, как наиболее близкому другу человека достаётся больше других.

При этом из всех названных слово "собач**и**на" произведено по вполне продуктивной модели (сравните "скот" - "скотина") и в чем-то может даже претендовать на ограниченную нормативность.

Comment: **Morkovkin**, cоб**а**чина чаще встречается, чем собач**и**на и тоже может претендовать на нормативность. А сейчас, когда домашних кошек стало куда больше, чем домашних собак, скорее уж им достаётся больше всего "ласковостей".

Comment: @Александра Я не про соб**а**чину вовсе. Для меня это собачье мясо и ничего более. Да и не имеет это отношения к вопросу.

Comment: Я говорю именно про обращение к живой и, разумеется, любимой собаке: "Ах ты, соб**а**чина моя хорошая!". И слово ассоциируется с такой же ситуацией, никак не с собачьим мясом 9_6

Я к тому, что странно говорить о нормативности. Это живая часть русского языка, уникальная для какой-то небольшой группы людей (употребляется внутри семьи, в кругу друзей...). Непонятно, почему в таком случае какие-то такие примеры могут "претендовать на ограниченную нормативность", а какие-то нет, даже если у некоторых вариантов есть сходство с "нормальными" словами.

Comment: Всё равно в официальном документе писать так будет нельзя, а использовать "ненормированные" варианты никому не запретишь. Но это не к Вам, вообще-то, вопрос, просто Вы очень серьёзно, академично, а потому странно ответили, и я не удержалась от комментария: ибо спорно, что от слова "собака" таких образований больше, чем от той же "кошки". Вот и всё, что я хотела сказать. Уже молчу)

Answer (score 4):

Но это же разговорно - шутливое, каждый хочет придумать что-то своё, оригинальное, только ему принадлежащее, как и укороченные имена друзей, обращения к кошкам:"Коша! Муся-пуся!Кошатина!"